# Javascript Regex to match $, but not ${

Tags: javascript, regex

I have just created a snippet generator tool for Sublime Text, Atom and VS Code, you can find it here: https://snippets.now.sh.

Snippets for these apps need to have the `$` escaped e.g. `$('.class')`, but not when it is used for placeholders e.g. `${1:foo}`.

What is the regex to match only occurrences of the `$` when it is not followed by a `{`?

Just to reiterate:

- Match this: `$foo`
- Don't match this: `${foo`

Comment: You are just looking for `\$(?!{)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew this works perrfectly, thank you. Would you like to submit it as an answer so I can mark it as 'Answered'?

Answer (score 5):

Use the following regex pattern:

```
\$(?!{).+\b
```

---

`(?!{)` - negative lookahead assertion, ensures that `$` is not followed by `{`

https://regex101.com/r/qQZIZQ/2

---

Additional case with *substitution* for the condition :

> **$** dollar signs need to be escaped, like so **\$**, but not when followed
>   by **{**, like so; **${**

```
\$(?!{)(.+\b)?
```

substitution: `\\$0`

https://regex101.com/r/qQZIZQ/4

Comment: Thanks @RomanPerekhrest, while this is close, it unfortunately doesn't fit my requirements. Let me clarify: `$` dollar signs need to be escaped, like so `\$`, but not when followed by `{`, like so; `${`. Your regex matches the `$` and everything after, but I just want to match the `$`. Does that make sense?

Comment: @Zander, can you elaborate more: is it about substitution of `$` sign? I mean, this entry `$('.class')` should be replaced with `\$('.class')` while this  `${1:foo}` should remain as is, right ?

Comment: @RomanPerekhest, yes you are correct. To clarify some more, any `$` sign needs to be escaped, no matter how many times they feature. The only exception should be if it is followed by a curly brace: `${`.

Comment: @Zander, check my update(with substitution)

Comment: RomanPerekhrest, thanks for your help. @WiktorStribiżew's solution actually solved it for me.